# How to get a Highchart to appear in HTML pages?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I wrote a python code to extract data from some text files then writing the data along with some html code and then save them to .html files. Each file should generate a Highchart extended heatmap. When I open the generated files they don't work, I see a blank html page. However, when I copied and pasted my html code into jsFiddle I was able to get a full working chart?  I'm an HTML newbie!
Here is what I have so far (Most of the actual data is deleted due to post limit)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />    

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>



<div id="container" style="height: 320px; width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<!-- Source: http://vikjavev.no/ver/highcharts-demos/heatmap.csv.php?year=2013 -->
<pre id="csv" style="display: none">Date,Time,Temperature
2013-1-1,6,0.0033
2013-1-1,7,0.0033
2013-1-1,8,0.1999
2013-1-1,9,0.3319
2013-1-1,10,0.3881
2013-1-1,11,0.3845
2013-1-1,12,0.3393
2013-1-1,13,0.2786
2013-1-1,14,0.2671
2013-1-1,15,0.2813
2013-1-1,16,0.2658
2013-1-1,17,0.2186
2013-1-1,18,0.0033
2013-1-2,6,0.0033
2013-1-2,7,0.0033
2013-1-2,8,0.1946
2013-1-2,9,0.2907
2013-1-2,10,0.3349
2013-1-2,11,0.3550
2013-1-2,12,0.3453
2013-1-2,13,0.3256
2013-1-2,14,0.3021
2013-1-2,15,0.2885
2013-1-2,16,0.2645
2013-1-2,17,0.2096
2013-1-2,18,0.0033
2013-1-3,6,0.0033
2013-1-3,7,0.0033
2013-1-3,8,0.1930
2013-1-3,9,0.2193
2013-1-3,10,0.2987
2013-1-3,11,0.3786
2013-1-3,12,0.3533
2013-1-3,13,0.3542
2013-1-3,14,0.3389
2013-1-3,15,0.3037
2013-1-3,16,0.2876
2013-1-3,17,0.2310
2013-1-3,18,0.0033
2013-1-4,6,0.0033
2013-1-4,7,0.0033
2013-1-4,8,0.2098
2013-1-4,9,0.2602
2013-1-4,10,0.3613
2013-1-4,11,0.4041
2013-1-4,12,0.3540
2013-1-4,13,0.3139
2013-1-4,14,0.2810
2013-1-4,15,0.2547
2013-1-4,16,0.2511
2013-1-4,17,0.2185
2013-1-4,18,0.1818
2013-1-5,6,0.0033
2013-1-5,7,0.0033
2013-1-5,8,0.2135
2013-1-5,9,0.3367
2013-1-5,10,0.3959
2013-1-5,11,0.3862
2013-1-5,12,0.3196
2013-1-5,13,0.2738
2013-1-5,14,0.2613
2013-1-5,15,0.2586
2013-1-5,16,0.2539
2013-1-5,17,0.2191
2013-1-5,18,0.1836
2013-1-6,6,0.0033
2013-1-6,7,0.0033
2013-1-6,8,0.2059
2013-1-6,9,0.2252
2013-1-6,10,0.2858
2013-1-6,11,0.3271
2013-1-6,12,0.3339
2013-1-6,13,0.3275
2013-1-6,14,0.2996
2013-1-6,15,0.2997
2013-1-6,16,0.2613
2013-1-6,17,0.2494
2013-1-6,18,0.0480
2013-1-7,6,0.0033
2013-1-7,7,0.0033
2013-1-7,8,0.0462
2013-1-7,9,0.2475
2013-1-7,10,0.2820
2013-1-7,11,0.3236
2013-1-7,12,0.3425
2013-1-7,13,0.3598
2013-1-7,14,0.3103
2013-1-7,15,0.2893
2013-1-7,16,0.2566
2013-1-7,17,0.2344
2013-1-7,18,0.0988
2013-1-8,6,0.0033
2013-1-8,7,0.0033
2013-1-8,8,0.1704
2013-1-8,9,0.2533
2013-1-8,10,0.3186
2013-1-8,11,0.3332
2013-1-8,12,0.3660
2013-1-8,13,0.3613
2013-1-8,14,0.3664
2013-1-8,15,0.3386
2013-1-8,16,0.3091
2013-1-8,17,0.2736
2013-1-8,18,0.0988
</pre>

                <script>
                $(function () {

    /**
     * This plugin extends Highcharts in two ways:
     * - Use HTML5 canvas instead of SVG for rendering of the heatmap squares. Canvas
     *   outperforms SVG when it comes to thousands of single shapes.
     * - Add a K-D-tree to find the nearest point on mouse move. Since we no longer have SVG shapes
     *   to capture mouseovers, we need another way of detecting hover points for the tooltip.
     */
    (function (H) {
        var Series = H.Series,
            each = H.each;

        /**
         * Create a hidden canvas to draw the graph on. The contents is later copied over
         * to an SVG image element.
         */
        Series.prototype.getContext = function () {
            if (!this.canvas) {
                this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                this.canvas.setAttribute('width', this.chart.chartWidth);
                this.canvas.setAttribute('height', this.chart.chartHeight);
                this.image = this.chart.renderer.image('', 0, 0, this.chart.chartWidth, this.chart.chartHeight).add(this.group);
                this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
            }
            return this.ctx;
        };

        /**
         * Draw the canvas image inside an SVG image
         */
        Series.prototype.canvasToSVG = function () {
            this.image.attr({ href: this.canvas.toDataURL('image/png') });
        };

        /**
         * Wrap the drawPoints method to draw the points in canvas instead of the slower SVG,
         * that requires one shape each point.
         */
        H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.heatmap.prototype, 'drawPoints', function () {

            var ctx = this.getContext();

            if (ctx) {

                // draw the columns
                each(this.points, function (point) {
                    var plotY = point.plotY,
                        shapeArgs;

                    if (plotY !== undefined && !isNaN(plotY) && point.y !== null) {
                        shapeArgs = point.shapeArgs;

                        ctx.fillStyle = point.pointAttr[''].fill;
                        ctx.fillRect(shapeArgs.x, shapeArgs.y, shapeArgs.width, shapeArgs.height);
                    }
                });

                this.canvasToSVG();

            } else {
                this.chart.showLoading('Your browser doesn't support HTML5 canvas, <br>please use a modern browser');

                // Uncomment this to provide low-level (slow) support in oldIE. It will cause script errors on
                // charts with more than a few thousand points.
                // arguments[0].call(this);
            }
        });
        H.seriesTypes.heatmap.prototype.directTouch = false; // Use k-d-tree
    }(Highcharts));


    var start;
    $('#container').highcharts({

        data: {
            csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
            parsed: function () {
                start = +new Date();
            }
        },

        chart: {
            type: 'heatmap',
            margin: [60, 10, 80, 50]
        },


        title: {
            text: 'Highcharts extended heat map',
            align: 'left',
            x: 40
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Temperature variation by day and hour through 2013',
            align: 'left',
            x: 40
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            min: Date.UTC(2013, 0, 1),
            max: Date.UTC(2014, 0, 1),
            labels: {
                align: 'left',
                x: 5,
                y: 14,
                format: '{value:%B}' // long month
            },
            showLastLabel: false,
            tickLength: 16
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value}:00'
            },
            minPadding: 0,
            maxPadding: 0,
            startOnTick: false,
            endOnTick: false,
            tickPositions: [6, 8, 10, 12, 16],
            tickWidth: 1,
            min: 6,
            max: 18,
            reversed: true
        },

        colorAxis: {
            stops: [
                [0, '#3060cf'],
                [0.5, '#fffbbc'],
                [0.9, '#c4463a'],
                [1, '#c4463a']
            ],
            min: 0,
            max: 1,
            startOnTick: false,
            endOnTick: false,
            labels: {
                format: '{value}?'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            borderWidth: 0,
            nullColor: '#EFEFEF',
            colsize: 24 * 36e5, // one day
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: 'Temperature<br/>',
                pointFormat: '{point.x:%e %b, %Y} {point.y}:00: <b>{point.value} ?</b>'
            },
            turboThreshold: Number.MAX_VALUE // #3404, remove after 4.0.5 release
        }]

    });
    console.log('Rendered in ' + (new Date() - start) + ' ms'); // eslint-disable-line no-console

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spotted the following error in your snippet:

```
{
    "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list",
    "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
    "lineno": 196,
    "colno": 40
}
```

Turns out, in line 186, you have a single quote in the word "doesn't" that wasn't escaped. You had:

`this.chart.showLoading('Your browser doesn't support HTML5 canvas, <br>please use a modern browser');`

It should be:

`this.chart.showLoading('Your browser doesn\'t support HTML5 canvas, <br>please use a modern browser');`

When I made this fix, I was able to get a heatmap to appear (see the updated snippet below).

Does this resolve your issue?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />    

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>



<div id="container" style="height: 320px; width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<!-- Source: http://vikjavev.no/ver/highcharts-demos/heatmap.csv.php?year=2013 -->
<pre id="csv" style="display: none">Date,Time,Temperature
2013-1-1,6,0.0033
2013-1-1,7,0.0033
2013-1-1,8,0.1999
2013-1-1,9,0.3319
2013-1-1,10,0.3881
2013-1-1,11,0.3845
2013-1-1,12,0.3393
2013-1-1,13,0.2786
2013-1-1,14,0.2671
2013-1-1,15,0.2813
2013-1-1,16,0.2658
2013-1-1,17,0.2186
2013-1-1,18,0.0033
2013-1-2,6,0.0033
2013-1-2,7,0.0033
2013-1-2,8,0.1946
2013-1-2,9,0.2907
2013-1-2,10,0.3349
2013-1-2,11,0.3550
2013-1-2,12,0.3453
2013-1-2,13,0.3256
2013-1-2,14,0.3021
2013-1-2,15,0.2885
2013-1-2,16,0.2645
2013-1-2,17,0.2096
2013-1-2,18,0.0033
2013-1-3,6,0.0033
2013-1-3,7,0.0033
2013-1-3,8,0.1930
2013-1-3,9,0.2193
2013-1-3,10,0.2987
2013-1-3,11,0.3786
2013-1-3,12,0.3533
2013-1-3,13,0.3542
2013-1-3,14,0.3389
2013-1-3,15,0.3037
2013-1-3,16,0.2876
2013-1-3,17,0.2310
2013-1-3,18,0.0033
2013-1-4,6,0.0033
2013-1-4,7,0.0033
2013-1-4,8,0.2098
2013-1-4,9,0.2602
2013-1-4,10,0.3613
2013-1-4,11,0.4041
2013-1-4,12,0.3540
2013-1-4,13,0.3139
2013-1-4,14,0.2810
2013-1-4,15,0.2547
2013-1-4,16,0.2511
2013-1-4,17,0.2185
2013-1-4,18,0.1818
2013-1-5,6,0.0033
2013-1-5,7,0.0033
2013-1-5,8,0.2135
2013-1-5,9,0.3367
2013-1-5,10,0.3959
2013-1-5,11,0.3862
2013-1-5,12,0.3196
2013-1-5,13,0.2738
2013-1-5,14,0.2613
2013-1-5,15,0.2586
2013-1-5,16,0.2539
2013-1-5,17,0.2191
2013-1-5,18,0.1836
2013-1-6,6,0.0033
2013-1-6,7,0.0033
2013-1-6,8,0.2059
2013-1-6,9,0.2252
2013-1-6,10,0.2858
2013-1-6,11,0.3271
2013-1-6,12,0.3339
2013-1-6,13,0.3275
2013-1-6,14,0.2996
2013-1-6,15,0.2997
2013-1-6,16,0.2613
2013-1-6,17,0.2494
2013-1-6,18,0.0480
2013-1-7,6,0.0033
2013-1-7,7,0.0033
2013-1-7,8,0.0462
2013-1-7,9,0.2475
2013-1-7,10,0.2820
2013-1-7,11,0.3236
2013-1-7,12,0.3425
2013-1-7,13,0.3598
2013-1-7,14,0.3103
2013-1-7,15,0.2893
2013-1-7,16,0.2566
2013-1-7,17,0.2344
2013-1-7,18,0.0988
2013-1-8,6,0.0033
2013-1-8,7,0.0033
2013-1-8,8,0.1704
2013-1-8,9,0.2533
2013-1-8,10,0.3186
2013-1-8,11,0.3332
2013-1-8,12,0.3660
2013-1-8,13,0.3613
2013-1-8,14,0.3664
2013-1-8,15,0.3386
2013-1-8,16,0.3091
2013-1-8,17,0.2736
2013-1-8,18,0.0988
</pre>

                <script>
                $(function () {

    /**
     * This plugin extends Highcharts in two ways:
     * - Use HTML5 canvas instead of SVG for rendering of the heatmap squares. Canvas
     *   outperforms SVG when it comes to thousands of single shapes.
     * - Add a K-D-tree to find the nearest point on mouse move. Since we no longer have SVG shapes
     *   to capture mouseovers, we need another way of detecting hover points for the tooltip.
     */
    (function (H) {
        var Series = H.Series,
            each = H.each;

        /**
         * Create a hidden canvas to draw the graph on. The contents is later copied over
         * to an SVG image element.
         */
        Series.prototype.getContext = function () {
            if (!this.canvas) {
                this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                this.canvas.setAttribute('width', this.chart.chartWidth);
                this.canvas.setAttribute('height', this.chart.chartHeight);
                this.image = this.chart.renderer.image('', 0, 0, this.chart.chartWidth, this.chart.chartHeight).add(this.group);
                this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
            }
            return this.ctx;
        };

        /**
         * Draw the canvas image inside an SVG image
         */
        Series.prototype.canvasToSVG = function () {
            this.image.attr({ href: this.canvas.toDataURL('image/png') });
        };

        /**
         * Wrap the drawPoints method to draw the points in canvas instead of the slower SVG,
         * that requires one shape each point.
         */
        H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.heatmap.prototype, 'drawPoints', function () {

            var ctx = this.getContext();

            if (ctx) {

                // draw the columns
                each(this.points, function (point) {
                    var plotY = point.plotY,
                        shapeArgs;

                    if (plotY !== undefined && !isNaN(plotY) && point.y !== null) {
                        shapeArgs = point.shapeArgs;

                        ctx.fillStyle = point.pointAttr[''].fill;
                        ctx.fillRect(shapeArgs.x, shapeArgs.y, shapeArgs.width, shapeArgs.height);
                    }
                });

                this.canvasToSVG();

            } else {
                this.chart.showLoading('Your browser doesn\'t support HTML5 canvas, <br>please use a modern browser');

                // Uncomment this to provide low-level (slow) support in oldIE. It will cause script errors on
                // charts with more than a few thousand points.
                // arguments[0].call(this);
            }
        });
        H.seriesTypes.heatmap.prototype.directTouch = false; // Use k-d-tree
    }(Highcharts));


    var start;
    $('#container').highcharts({

        data: {
            csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
            parsed: function () {
                start = +new Date();
            }
        },

        chart: {
            type: 'heatmap',
            margin: [60, 10, 80, 50]
        },


        title: {
            text: 'Highcharts extended heat map',
            align: 'left',
            x: 40
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Temperature variation by day and hour through 2013',
            align: 'left',
            x: 40
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            min: Date.UTC(2013, 0, 1),
            max: Date.UTC(2014, 0, 1),
            labels: {
                align: 'left',
                x: 5,
                y: 14,
                format: '{value:%B}' // long month
            },
            showLastLabel: false,
            tickLength: 16
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value}:00'
            },
            minPadding: 0,
            maxPadding: 0,
            startOnTick: false,
            endOnTick: false,
            tickPositions: [6, 8, 10, 12, 16],
            tickWidth: 1,
            min: 6,
            max: 18,
            reversed: true
        },

        colorAxis: {
            stops: [
                [0, '#3060cf'],
                [0.5, '#fffbbc'],
                [0.9, '#c4463a'],
                [1, '#c4463a']
            ],
            min: 0,
            max: 1,
            startOnTick: false,
            endOnTick: false,
            labels: {
                format: '{value}?'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            borderWidth: 0,
            nullColor: '#EFEFEF',
            colsize: 24 * 36e5, // one day
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: 'Temperature<br/>',
                pointFormat: '{point.x:%e %b, %Y} {point.y}:00: <b>{point.value} ?</b>'
            },
            turboThreshold: Number.MAX_VALUE // #3404, remove after 4.0.5 release
        }]

    });
    console.log('Rendered in ' + (new Date() - start) + ' ms'); // eslint-disable-line no-console

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks it works. However, when I double-click the html file to open it in a browser I'm not able to see anything! what could be the reason?

Comment: @Julia_arch Glad that helped! Just so I'm clear, what do you mean by "double-click the html file to open it in a browser"? Double-click it from where?

Comment: I apologize if I use the wrong terminology, I'm new to HTML.What I do is I save the HTML code to a .html file on my laptop. Then I double-click the .html file to open it on my browser.

Comment: @Julia_arch Ah! I see the problem. Add "https" to the first script call (for the jQuery code). You need the full URL to run the HTML file from your laptop. That should solve the problem.

Comment: I finally got it to work by double-clicking it. Thank you so much. I've been working on this for two days with no luck.